# Can't get a border around a html div element

Tags: css, html, border

I can't figure out why I can't get a border around my div here. My jsfiddle is:

http://jsfiddle.net/4HnKs/1/

I must just be crazy from staring at my computer screen but if you look at the class `verticalmembersmenu` in the CSS, I can't for the life of me figure out why I can't get the border around the div.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are using HTML style comments in your CSS, that seems to be breaking the rendering, take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/4HnKs/3/

Some info on comments over at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#comments

Answer (score 9):

u can give inline style to div as

```
 <div class="verticalmembersmenu" style = "border:1px solid black;">
```

or

```
.verticalmembersmenu ul{
list-style:none; border:1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It took me a while to find, but the problem actually has to do with your css formatting. The css doesn't recognize html comment tags, but instead uses /* */.

```
 <!--MEMBERS LAYOUT START -->
.verticalmembersmenu {
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    border:1px solid black;
}

.verticalmembersmenu ul{
    list-style:none;
}


<!--MEMBERS LAYOUT END -->
```

Answer (score 1):

please give the border in ul tag.

```
.verticalmembersmenu ul{
    list-style:none; border:1px solid black;
    }
```

Comment: -1 There is invalid syntax in the CSS which is causing the issue.