# css div class properties not found

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with making a div find and use the css properties for a specified class.

Here is the css and html:

```css
.minor-heading-text {border: thick solid black}
.minor-heading-text h4 {padding: 5px; font-style: italic; color: #111}
.minor-heading-text p {font-size: 110%}
```

```html
<div class="minor-heading-text">
  <h4>My heading</h4>
  <p>My paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Also, on my webpage, the div is contained within a few other divs, each with a unique id and associated styles.

In my page, the "h4" and "p" elements take on the specified css properties, but the "div" does not make a border. In the firefox debugger, it seems that the "minor-heading-text" class is not found for the div, even though it is found for the contained h4 and p elements. 
The above code works fine when I run the code snippet alone, but doesn't work in my page.

I am quite new to making websites so I feel there is something basic about divs and classes that I do not know. Please forgive my ignorance.

I tried changing the css to "div.minor-heading-text" and got the same result.

Anyway does anybody know why the div is not taking on the class properties that I want?

Thank you in advance for your help.

P.s. my website is in development so I prefer not to post the address publicly, but if someone needs to see it then I can post it.

Comment: There can be other classes that block it, we need to see more of the code that is not working.

Comment: can't understand your exact question.

Comment: Nothing wrong in your code. check this working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xzps4u7b/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys! I will use the jsfiddle in the future.

I found out that I had improper commenting style on the previous line.

Specifically, I had been using double slash "//" style commenting in the previous line

```css
//my comment
.minor-heading-text {border: thick solid black}
```

To fix it, I changed it to the proper /* */ style:

```
/*my comment*/
.minor-heading-text {border: thick solid black}
```

And there was no more problem.

So, yea, main point use proper css commenting.

By the way, I found a similar problem [at this question about css borders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798677/cant-get-a-border-around-my-div)